# JSprit not using closer vehicle, due to time issues

Tags: java, jsprit, vehicle-routing

Single-job schedule with two vehicles. One vehicle starts close to the job, the other starts far from the job. Seems it should prefer to use the closer vehicle, as there's a cost-per-distance. But it uses the farther one, if there's a non-zero `setCostPerWaitingTime()`. Why?

```
public void testUseCloserVehicleWhenCostsAreSet() throws Exception {
    VehicleType type = VehicleTypeImpl.Builder.newInstance("generic")
            .setCostPerDistance(0.017753)
            //.setCostPerTransportTime(1.0)
            .setCostPerWaitingTime(1.0)
            .build();
    double serviceTime = 420.0;
    Location pointA = Location.newInstance(100.0, 100.0);
    Location pointB = Location.newInstance(100.0, 200.0);
    Location closeToPointA = Location.newInstance(110.0, 110.0);
    Location farFromPointA = Location.newInstance(500.0, 110.0);
    VehicleRoutingProblem vrp = VehicleRoutingProblem.Builder
            .newInstance()
            .setFleetSize(VehicleRoutingProblem.FleetSize.FINITE)
            .addVehicle(VehicleImpl.Builder.newInstance("CloseBy")
                    .setType(type)
                    .setStartLocation(closeToPointA)
                    .build())
            .addVehicle(VehicleImpl.Builder.newInstance("FarAway")
                    .setType(type)
                    .setStartLocation(farFromPointA)
                    .build())
            .addJob(Shipment.Builder.newInstance("123")
                    .setPickupLocation(pointA)
                    .setPickupServiceTime(serviceTime)
                    .setDeliveryLocation(pointB)
                    .setDeliveryServiceTime(serviceTime)
                    .setPickupTimeWindow(new TimeWindow(36000.0, 36360.0))
                    .setDeliveryTimeWindow(new TimeWindow(36360.0, 36720.0))
                    .setMaxTimeInVehicle(720.0)
                    .build())
            .build();

    VehicleRoutingAlgorithm algorithm = Jsprit.Builder.newInstance(vrp)
            .buildAlgorithm();

    VehicleRoutingProblemSolution bestSolution = Solutions.bestOf(algorithm.searchSolutions());
    SolutionPrinterWithTimes.print(vrp, bestSolution, SolutionPrinterWithTimes.Print.VERBOSE);
    System.out.flush();
    assertEquals("CloseBy", bestSolution.getRoutes().iterator().next().getVehicle().getId());
}
```

Result:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| solution                                                 |
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
| indicator     | value                                    |
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
| costs         | 35616.03246830352                        | 
| noVehicles    | 1                                        | 
| unassgndJobs  | 0                                        | 
+----------------------------------------------------------+
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| detailed solution                                                                                                              |
+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| route   | vehicle              | activity              | job             | arrTime         | endTime         | costs           |
+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1       | FarAway              | start                 | -               | undef           | 0               | 0               |
| 1       | FarAway              | pickupShipment        | 123             | 400             | 36420           | 35607           |
| 1       | FarAway              | deliverShipment       | 123             | 36520           | 36940           | 35609           |
| 1       | FarAway              | end                   | -               | 37350           | undef           | 35616           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :CloseBy
Actual   :FarAway
```

I suspect it has something to do with the vehicle arriving at `400` for a job that can't start until `36000`. Is there a way to prevent that, so the vehicle starts only as early as needed to reach the first job? Does `setCostPerWaitingTime` do something other than what I think?

Comment: Is there to add a job to vehicle CloseBy  which he is currently delivering, we want to check if new job is suitable for him or not

Answer (score 0):

Here's a comparison of the job with only the `CloseBy` vehicle.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| detailed solution                                                                                                              |
+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| route   | vehicle              | activity              | job             | arrTime         | endTime         | costs           |
+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1       | FarAway              | start                 | -               | undef           | 0               | 0               |
| 1       | FarAway              | pickupShipment        | 123             | 400             | 36420           | 35607           |
| 1       | FarAway              | deliverShipment       | 123             | 36520           | 36940           | 35609           |
| 1       | FarAway              | end                   | -               | 37350           | undef           | 35616           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| detailed solution                                                                                                              |
+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| route   | vehicle              | activity              | job             | arrTime         | endTime         | costs           |
+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1       | CloseBy              | start                 | -               | undef           | 0               | 0               |
| 1       | CloseBy              | pickupShipment        | 123             | 14              | 36420           | 35986           |
| 1       | CloseBy              | deliverShipment       | 123             | 36520           | 36940           | 35988           |
| 1       | CloseBy              | end                   | -               | 37031           | undef           | 35989           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I think the problem is that the CloseBy vehicle arrives sooner, so it pays higher wait costs, while the other vehicle is driving during that time so pays less in wait costs. This would be mitigated if the vehicle didn't start until it needed to, but I'm unsure how to set that up.